# What is this code from createEditor actually doing (Rapid Gui Programming With Python and Qt)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I'm going through "Rapid Gui Programming With Python and Qt". In chapter 14, we implement our own delegate class. One of the functions is called createEditor. Here's the code for it:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    if index.column() == TEU:
        spinbox = QSpinBox(parent)
        spinbox.setRange(0, 200000)
        spinbox.setSingleStep(1000)
        spinbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        return spinbox
    elif index.column() == OWNER:
        combobox = QComboBox(parent)
        combobox.addItems(sorted(index.model().owners))
        combobox.setEditable(True)
        return combobox
    elif index.column() == COUNTRY:
        combobox = QComboBox(parent)
        combobox.addItems(sorted(index.model().countries))
        combobox.setEditable(True)
        return combobox
    elif index.column() == NAME:
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        self.connect(editor, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),
                     self.commitAndCloseEditor)
        return editor
    elif index.column() == DESCRIPTION:
        editor = richtextlineedit.RichTextLineEdit(parent)
        self.connect(editor, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),
                     self.commitAndCloseEditor)
        return editor
    else:
        return QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option,
                                                index)
```

Here's the code for commitAndCloseEditor:

```
def commitAndCloseEditor(self):
    editor = self.sender()
    if isinstance(editor, (QTextEdit, QLineEdit)):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("commitData(QWidget*)"), editor)
        self.emit(SIGNAL("closeEditor(QWidget*)"), editor)
```

I understand what's happening for the TEU, OWNER, COUNTRY and DESCRIPTION columns. However, I don't see what's being achieved in the NAME column. In fact, I commented the NAME code out so the base function would be called and I can't see any difference whatsoever...

Comment: Note that that book has some years, which means that *current* versions of `PyQt`/`Qt` might have different behaviour then the one the author took into account when writing the book. The purpose of the `NAME` column is pretty clear: if the user press enter it should commit the edit and close the editor. Whether the code was put there because earlier versions didn't have this behaviour or simply to uniform the function I don't know, and *nobody* can answer, except the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.connect(editor, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),
                 self.commitAndCloseEditor)
```

What that line does is call Qt's `connect` function to create a link between a `SIGNAL`, which in this case is `returnPressed`, and a `SLOT` which is a function and in this case is the `commitAndCloseEditor`. Without digging into the code too much it looks like it's there so when the return key is pressed and `commitAndCloseEditor` function is triggered to update the data source and close an editor view for the table.

Comment: I understand that. However, upon testing it further, that doesn't seem to achieve anything at all. If I comment the "NAME" part out it works exactly the same. If I change the commitAndCloseEditor to only pass, it still works exactly the same... I can't understand what the code is achieving that the base function wouldn't achieve.

Comment: Notice how `NAME` and `DESCRIPTION` are the same? I imagine if you double click on the `NAME` or `DESCRIPTION` fields you'd get an editor box to change the contents. Wouldn't be able to say for certain without looking at the example.